# Android tabbar doesn't respond

Tags: android

I'm working on android app which uses tabbar, navigating through intents using TabGroupActivity,

```
    Intent homeIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, SomeActivity.class);
    homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startChildActivity("SomeActivity", homeIntent);
```

I want to redirect the my home activity from where ever i clicked tabbar home icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your TabActivity class set OnTouchListener to the each tab view when setting the tabs,

```
view.setOnTouchListener(this);
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HomeActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator(view).setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

TabActivity class call onTouch method

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    // use getTabHost().getCurrentTabView to decide if the current tab is
    // touched again
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
            && view.equals(getTabHost().getCurrentTabView())) {
        // use getTabHost().getCurrentView() to get a handle to the view
        // which is displayed in the tab - and to get this views context
        if(getTabHost().getCurrentTabTag().equals("home")) {
            // do what ever you want when tab home icon
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```